# datatable.js stop working if autocomplete starts

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have written 
1) scripts using datatable.js to show data
2) autocomplete method

1. PortletDraggable.init();
2. FormFileUpload.init();
3. EducationalQualification.init();
4. WorkExperience.init();
5. Supervisions.init();
6. Awards.init();
7. Publication.init();

All these are datatable methods working properly. But when I add jquery.auto-complete.js script reference, these methods stop working and autocomplete start working.

Where is the problem, please suggest.

```
<script>

    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });


    //  var oTable = null;

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        App.init();
        PortletDraggable.init();
        FormFileUpload.init();
        EducationalQualification.init();
        WorkExperience.init();
        Supervisions.init();
        Awards.init();
        Publication.init();
    });

        var tmpMem = 0; var tmpAward = 0; var tmpPub = 0;
        // Js For Autocomplete
        $('input[name=SearchUser]').autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {
                tmpMem = 0; tmpAward = 0; tmpPub = 0;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("SearchUser", "Profile")',
                    data: { FirstName: $("#SearchUser").val() },
                    //  url: "/Profile/SearchUser?FirstName=" + $("#SearchUser").val(),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //       dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        // code to show loading image
                        //$(".ui-content").css("opacity", "0.4");
                        //$("#imgLoader").attr("style", "display:block");
                        //var df = document.getElementById('imgLoader');
                        //df.style.position = 'absolute';
                        //var wd = ($(window).width() / 2) - 45;
                        //var hg = ($(window).height() / 2) - 60;
                        //df.style.left = wd + "px";
                        //df.style.top = hg + "px";
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                         //hide loading image
                        $(".ui-content").css("opacity", "1.0");
                        $("#imgLoader").attr("style", "display:none");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                           alert(data.data[0].Fname);
                        response($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                Sn: item.Sn, Fname: item.Fname, Mname: item.Uname, Lname: item.Lname, Title: item.Title,
                                Image: item.Image, Organization: item.Organization, JobTitle: item.JobTitle,
                                Awardname: item.Awardname, AwardYear: item.AwardYear, Pubname: item.Pubname, Pubtype: item.Pubtype, TabType: item.TabType
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //var domainURL = $("#domainurl").val();
                //window.location = domainURL + "/home/NeighborProfile?id=" + ui.item.id;
                // alert(ui.item.Sn);
            }
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            //     alert(item);="

            if (item.TabType == "member") {
                if (tmpMem == 0) {
                    tmpMem = 1;
                    return $("<li  class='SearchUserLi'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(

                   "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                       "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                       "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                             item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                             "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                       "</span>" +
                       "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + item.JobTitle + "</span>" +
                   "</a>"
                   ).prepend("<span class='SearchUsercategory'> Members  </span>").appendTo(ul);
                }
                return $("<li   class='SearchUserLi'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(
                      "<hr class='SearchUserHr'>" +
                    "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                        "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                        "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                              item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                              "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
                        "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + item.JobTitle + "</span>" +
                    "</a>"
                    ).appendTo(ul);
            }
            else if (item.TabType == "award") {
                if (tmpAward == 0) {
                    tmpAward = 1;
                    return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(

                   "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                       "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                       "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                             item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                             "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                       "</span>" +
                       "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Awardname + "(" + item.AwardYear + ")" + "</span>" +
                   "</a>"
                   ).prepend("<span class='SearchUsercategory'> Awards  </span>").appendTo(ul)
                }
                return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(
                     "<hr class='SearchUserHr'>" +
                    "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                        "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                        "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                              item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                              "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
                        "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Awardname + "(" + item.AwardYear + ")" + "</span>" +
                    "</a>"
                    ).appendTo(ul);

            }
            else if (item.TabType == "publications") {
                if (tmpPub == 0) {
                    tmpPub = 1;
                    return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(

                   "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                       "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                       "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                             item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                             "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                       "</span>" +
                       "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Pubname + "," + item.Pubtype + "</span>" +
                   "</a>"
                   ).prepend("<span class='SearchUsercategory'> Publications  </span>").appendTo(ul)
                }
                return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(
                      "<hr class='SearchUserHr'>" +
                    "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                        "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                        "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                              item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                              "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
                        "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Pubname + "," + item.Pubtype + "</span>" +
                    "</a>"
                    ).appendTo(ul);

            }
        };



</script>
```

Comment: any errors?? `console.log()` ??!!

Comment: Can you add your auto-complete block inside document ready function.Let it be initialize properly.

Comment: @Amit - still not working

Comment: Please check autocomplete js [link](http://ris.sahyadritechnologies.com/assets/scripts/jquery.auto-complete.js)
,
if I remove second jquery block which is under /* docs.jquery.com/UI/Widget /*, other part works but autocomplete stops

Answer (score 0):

After you include jQuery, add the following in a script tag immediately after it. Hope this solves your problem.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: you should post your html and javascript code in respective blocks inside fiddle to make it work somehow.

Comment: I have use ASP.net MVC3 framework as backend(to get JSON Data)

you can check the html source at http://research.athahsoftech.com/profile

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your datepicker or autocomplete would work like this.  They are both adding functionality to DOM elements when the DOM may not be ready.  Try something like this:

```
<script>

    var initFields = function() {

        //Date Picker
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        });

        //Autocomplete
        var tmpMem = 0; var tmpAward = 0; var tmpPub = 0;
        // Js For Autocomplete
        $('input[name=SearchUser]').autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {
                tmpMem = 0; tmpAward = 0; tmpPub = 0;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("SearchUser", "Profile")',
                    data: { FirstName: $("#SearchUser").val() },
                    //  url: "/Profile/SearchUser?FirstName=" + $("#SearchUser").val(),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //       dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        // code to show loading image
                        //$(".ui-content").css("opacity", "0.4");
                        //$("#imgLoader").attr("style", "display:block");
                        //var df = document.getElementById('imgLoader');
                        //df.style.position = 'absolute';
                        //var wd = ($(window).width() / 2) - 45;
                        //var hg = ($(window).height() / 2) - 60;
                        //df.style.left = wd + "px";
                        //df.style.top = hg + "px";
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                         //hide loading image
                        $(".ui-content").css("opacity", "1.0");
                        $("#imgLoader").attr("style", "display:none");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                           alert(data.data[0].Fname);
                        response($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                Sn: item.Sn, Fname: item.Fname, Mname: item.Uname, Lname: item.Lname, Title: item.Title,
                                Image: item.Image, Organization: item.Organization, JobTitle: item.JobTitle,
                                Awardname: item.Awardname, AwardYear: item.AwardYear, Pubname: item.Pubname, Pubtype: item.Pubtype, TabType: item.TabType
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //var domainURL = $("#domainurl").val();
                //window.location = domainURL + "/home/NeighborProfile?id=" + ui.item.id;
                // alert(ui.item.Sn);
            }
        }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            //     alert(item);="

            if (item.TabType == "member") {
                if (tmpMem == 0) {
                    tmpMem = 1;
                    return $("<li  class='SearchUserLi'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(

                   "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                       "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                       "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                             item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                             "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                       "</span>" +
                       "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + item.JobTitle + "</span>" +
                   "</a>"
                   ).prepend("<span class='SearchUsercategory'> Members  </span>").appendTo(ul);
                }
                return $("<li   class='SearchUserLi'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(
                      "<hr class='SearchUserHr'>" +
                    "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                        "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                        "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                              item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                              "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
                        "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + item.JobTitle + "</span>" +
                    "</a>"
                    ).appendTo(ul);
            }
            else if (item.TabType == "award") {
                if (tmpAward == 0) {
                    tmpAward = 1;
                    return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(

                   "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                       "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                       "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                             item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                             "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                       "</span>" +
                       "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Awardname + "(" + item.AwardYear + ")" + "</span>" +
                   "</a>"
                   ).prepend("<span class='SearchUsercategory'> Awards  </span>").appendTo(ul)
                }
                return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(
                     "<hr class='SearchUserHr'>" +
                    "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                        "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                        "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                              item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                              "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
                        "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Awardname + "(" + item.AwardYear + ")" + "</span>" +
                    "</a>"
                    ).appendTo(ul);

            }
            else if (item.TabType == "publications") {
                if (tmpPub == 0) {
                    tmpPub = 1;
                    return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(

                   "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                       "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                       "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                             item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                             "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                       "</span>" +
                       "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Pubname + "," + item.Pubtype + "</span>" +
                   "</a>"
                   ).prepend("<span class='SearchUsercategory'> Publications  </span>").appendTo(ul)
                }
                return $("<li style='padding:0px!important;height:80px'></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(
                      "<hr class='SearchUserHr'>" +
                    "<a href='  ' class='SearchUserLink'>" +
                        "<img  src='" + item.Image + "' alt='" + item.Fname + "' class='SearchUserImg'>" +
                        "<span class='searchUserLight'>" +
                              item.Title + ". " + item.Fname +
                              "<span style=' font-weight: bold;color:black'>" + "  " + item.Organization + "</span>" +
                        "</span>" +
                        "<span style='  font-size : 10px; color: #3B5998;'>" + "  " + item.Pubname + "," + item.Pubtype + "</span>" +
                    "</a>"
                    ).appendTo(ul);

            }
        };


    };
    //  var oTable = null;

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        App.init();
        PortletDraggable.init();
        FormFileUpload.init();
        EducationalQualification.init();
        WorkExperience.init();
        Supervisions.init();
        Awards.init();
        Publication.init();
        initFields();
    });   

</script>
```

If that doesn't work, then you may want to check what all JavaScript files you are including to ensure all their versions are compatible, and no two are defining the same functions/objects.

Comment: @JayantBramhankar Have you solved your problem?  Did you try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a single Autocomplete script reference, simply add jquery.ui complete bundle script reference. I had a similar problem, but after adding jquery.ui and removing autocomplete scripts, everything started to work fine. Hope it helps