# javascript jquery auto complete and data table

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use both autocomplete and data tables at the same time, same page?  `autocomplete.js` and `jquery.min.js` are not working together, unless I delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The same question is answered here :

[datatable.js stop working if autocomplete starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726679/datatable-js-stop-working-if-autocomplete-starts)

Please refer the above link.

After you include jQuery, add the following in a script tag immediately after it. Hope this solves your problem.

`jQuery.noConflict();`